# Not able to start mongodb in local as docker container

Tags: docker, devops

I am not able to start the mongodb in local using the docker container, below were the error and configurations used

- Tryig to start mongodb as a container in local for connecting through spring boot application

```
ould not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:pass12345@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express  | /node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:292
mongo-express  |                 const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
mongo-express  |                                      ^
mongo-express  | 
mongo-express  | MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
mongo-express  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:292:38)
mongo-express  |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
mongo-express  |     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
mongo-express  |   reason: TopologyDescription {
mongo-express  |     type: 'Unknown',
mongo-express  |     servers: Map(1) {
mongo-express  |       'mongodb:27017' => ServerDescription {
mongo-express  |         address: 'mongodb:27017',
mongo-express  |         type: 'Unknown',
mongo-express  |         hosts: [],
mongo-express  |         passives: [],
mongo-express  |         arbiters: [],
mongo-express  |         tags: {},
mongo-express  |         minWireVersion: 0,
mongo-express  |         maxWireVersion: 0,
mongo-express  |         roundTripTime: -1,
mongo-express  |         lastUpdateTime: 1701047,
mongo-express  |         lastWriteDate: 0,
mongo-express  |         error: MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
mongo-express  |             at connectionFailureError (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:387:20)
mongo-express  |             at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:310:22)
mongo-express  |             at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
mongo-express  |             at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
mongo-express  |             at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
mongo-express  |             at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
mongo-express  |             at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
mongo-express  |           cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
mongo-express  |               at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
mongo-express  |             errno: -3008,
mongo-express  |             code: 'ENOTFOUND',
mongo-express  |             syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
mongo-express  |             hostname: 'mongodb'
mongo-express  |           },
mongo-express  |           [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
mongo-express  |         },
mongo-express  |         topologyVersion: null,
mongo-express  |         setName: null,
mongo-express  |         setVersion: null,
mongo-express  |         electionId: null,
mongo-express  |         logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
mongo-express  |         primary: null,
mongo-express  |         me: null,
mongo-express  |         '$clusterTime': null
mongo-express  |       }
mongo-express  |     },
mongo-express  |     stale: false,
mongo-express  |     compatible: true,
mongo-express  |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
mongo-express  |     localThresholdMS: 15,
mongo-express  |     setName: null,
mongo-express  |     maxElectionId: null,
mongo-express  |     maxSetVersion: null,
mongo-express  |     commonWireVersion: 0,
mongo-express  |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
mongo-express  |   },
mongo-express  |   code: undefined,
mongo-express  |   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
mongo-express  | }
mongo-express  | 
mongo-express  | Node.js v18.19.0
mongo-express exited with code 1
```

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass12345
    volumes:
      - /Users/Shared/Docker/mongodb-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - tgc-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo 10.10.10.60:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=****
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin123
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - tgc-network
    ports:
      - 8083:8081
    healthcheck:
      test: wget --quiet --tries=3 --spider http://admin:admin123@10.10.10.60:8081 || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  mongodb-data:
    name: mongodb-data
networks:
  tgc-network:
    name: tgc-network
```

Not able to find what's going wrong in the configurations

- I tried removing the images and restart, but it's reccurring

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your environment is not set correctly

- ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=****

Comment: I replaced the actual password with *’s. In my configuration it has the valid password

Comment: I can't reproduce this error in my env. Maybe you can try to clean the mount path (/Users/Shared/Docker/mongodb-data) and restart it again

Comment: Thanks for quick response, were you able to start service with above configurations, can you please share the working version, probably will try with that

Comment: I just changed the password:
- ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=pass12345
But The error you encountered is unrelated to the password. I suggest you firstly start mongodb service with command `docker-compose up -d mongodb` and ensure it runs without error and then start express

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to mongodb service not being ready when express is trying to connect.
In your Docker Compose file, you have already specified that mongo-express depends on mongodb using depends_on. Unfortunately, depends_on waits for the container and not for the service inside the container.

Try adding a wait script in your mongo-express service to ensure that it only starts after the mongodb service is ready like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
     ...
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    command: /bin/sh -c "echo 'Waiting for mongodb...' && while ! nc -z mongodb 27017; do sleep 1; done && echo 'mongodb is ready.' && mongo-express"
    environment:
               ...
```